# preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']'

Tags: php

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) esta la linea del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por cierto, la proxima vez que preguntes algo en stack usa codigo escrito en vez de imagenes, asi nos sera mas facil replicar tu codigo

Comment: Y un título que sea significativo, si alguien más tiene alguna pregunta similar jamás podría encontrar la respuesta.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error esta en que esta en el '/' al final de la regex la regex debe quedar asi `preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]+$/','string')` si quieres que la regex tambien acepte diagonales '/' debes de escapar el caracter con una diagonal invertida '' `preg_match('/^[A-z0-9\/]+$/','string')`

Comment: muchas gracias no me habia percatado muchas gracias